# Error while connecting to oracle through entity framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity framework 6.1.3 version.
I am using Oracle 11g version.
I am trying to connect to Oracle through Entity framework.
I am facing issue while trying to open connection.
Below is my config file and code to connect:

```
----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FOLADB" connectionString="Data Source=HRFOLATEST1;User id=***;Password=***;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccessClient" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccessClient.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccessClient" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

```
 string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SConnectionString"].ToString();
 OracleConnection connSSTrack = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            connSSTrack.Open();
```

I am getting the below error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

When I am using the same connection string in another asp.net application,it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your TNS settings. You can supply them is your connect string or find them in your tnsnames.ora. https://blog.vijay.name/2012/11/oracle-managed-odp-net/